# getting error in .android keystore while generating MD5 fingerprint

Tags: google-maps

I want to use google map in my android application..while generating the MD5 fingerprint i type the command in console 
keytool -list -alias androidkey -keystore debug.keystore 
that asked for password i didnt know the password so i typed the wrong one so it showed the error keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was
incorrect
so i open the debug.keystore file and after closing the file now its not showing the debug.keystore file..it is showing only debug file.. now again i tried generating MD5 it is showin error 
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: debug.keystore
what should i do? plz help..

Answer (score 1):

You can install Keytool plugin for Eclipse. Keytool is an useful plugin that creats and manages certificates. if you want to install, add http://keytool.sourceforge.net/update to your available software list from  Help >> Install New Software menu.